# What does a KeyError: <bound method > mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create the degrees project from CS50 Intro to AI. In the project I have to find the shortest path between two actors through the movies they have starred in like the Six Degrees of Bacon Game. To do this I have been trying to change the solve function in maze.py from the lecture.

I am receiving the following error:

```
KeyError: <bound method QueueFrontier.remove of <util.QueueFrontier object at 0x00000276751F1CD0>>
```

The following is my function:

```py
def shortest_path(source, target):
    start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
    frontier = QueueFrontier()
    frontier.add(start)

    explored = set()

    while True:
        if frontier.empty():
            return None
        node = frontier.remove
        explored.add(node)

        if node == target:
            movies = []
            actors = []
            while node.parent is not None:
                movies.append(node.movie)
                actors.append(node.actor)
                node = node.parent
            movies.reverse()
            actors.reverse()
            target = (movies, actors)
            return
        
        explored.add(node)

        for action, state in neighbors_for_person(node):
            if not frontier.contains_state(state) and state in explored:
                child = Node(state=state, parent=node, action=action)
                frontier.add(child)
```

The comments below have fixed my previous problem. Now whenever I test the code with two actors, nothing happens; the text cursor only blinks.

Below is my updated code:

```py
def shortest_path(source, target):
    start = Node(state=source, parent=None, action=None)
    frontier = QueueFrontier()
    frontier.add(start)

    explored = set()

    while True:
        if frontier.empty():
            return None
        node = frontier.remove()
        explored.add(node)
 
        #All of the errors are in this block of code
        if node.state == target:
            print("this happens")
            actions = []
            cells = []
            while node.parent is not None:
                cells.append(node.state)
                actions.append(node.action)
                node = node.parent
            cells.reverse()
            actions.reverse()
            target = (actions, cells)
            return target
        

        for action, state in neighbors_for_person(node.state):
            if not frontier.contains_state(state) and  state not in explored:
                child = Node(state=state, parent=node, action=action)
                frontier.add(child)
```

Note: The print statement does not print anything in the terminal.

Comment: looks like `frontier.remove` is a method, therefore it should be `frontier.remove()`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter adding ```()``` and changing ```node``` to ```node.state``` removed the error. Whenever I test it with actors I know are connected, I get the answer "Not connected." Would you happen to know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: That's not a standard Python error, and it's not in the code you posted. So I don't see how we can tell what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above solve 2 problems, but there are still others. You can find these by going through your code and checking variable values on each `while` loop. Use the debugger or add print statements.

The 'Not connected' error is due to 3 errors in the `if node == target` block. They are:

1. Confusing the variable `node` (which is a `Node` object) with the person's id (saved as `node.state` and is an integer stored as a string variable). This occurs in multiple places:

   - When you check `node == target` you will always get False (because a Node will not be equal to the target person's id).
   - When you create the `movies and actors` lists, you use `node.movie and node.actor` (instead of `.action and .state`). You haven't gotten an error (yet) because you never enter this code block due to error 1 above.
2. You don't return anything after you create the `movies and actors` lists.
3. In addition, you create a tuple from the 2 lists, but it's not what
   you think. (You will get an error if you return `target` as-is.)

Your logic to check neighbors and add new nodes needs attention. Your `if` statement has `and state in explored`. You only want to add nodes if state is NOT in explored. Also, checking the explored set first is faster than checking the list (which is slow for large lists).

Finally, your implementation of the explored set is flawed, so it doesn't really improve performance. This set represents all actor ids that have been added to the frontier. We do this so we don't add the same actor twice. Your code doesn't add actor ids until you pop them from the frontier. Once you get this working correctly, the explored set will include every actor you have added to the frontier (even those removed them during the search). Then you can remove `not frontier.contains_state(state)` from the `if` statement, because it is redundant. Note: you have `explored.add(node)`in 2 places. The 2nd is a duplicate of the 1st.

Comment: I changed my code to `if node.state == target`, which did not fix the issue and is causing none of the code do be executed below it (I checked with print statements). Do you know why this might be? (Thank you for explaining the mistakes in my code.)

Comment: That's a start. Did you fix the other errors in that code block? It wold be helpful if you updated your code to show all the changes. There are 2 returns. I suspect you are hitting the 1st one `return None` after `if frontier.empty():`. Why do I say that? The 2nd one has `return` (w/out a value) and will cause an error in `main()` Also, did you fix the error after you get neighbors? With `and state in explored` you will never add actors/states that are not in `explored`. If you don't fix this, you will quickly empty the frontier.

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestions but am facing a new problem. Whenever I try to test my code with two actors, only the flashing text cursor appears; nothing else. I have included my updated code in my question if you could take a look at it. Thank you for helping!

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors. If you don't see "this happens" printed, you haven't found the target, and you are still in the search loop. That can happen when you haven't optimized your algorithm, especially when the frontier gets large. Use the small dataset for testing. There are only 15 people so the search is fast(er). Try Tom Hanks and Tom Cruise - they only have 2 degrees of separation.

Comment: your explanation was helpful. I was able to fix most of the problems, but I do not understand what the problem is with `target`. In my current code I create a tuple and append that to a list, but I am receiving this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Why might that be?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the code that creates the solution path. If you are still defining `target = (actions, cells)`, then you have a tuple of lists, and you need a list of tuples of form `(movie/action, person/state`). Also, target is an input and you are overwriting it's value and returning it. While not "wrong" it's confusing. It would be better to create a new variable for the path and return that value.